# What should $\mu$ be here in order for the logistic map to be stable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics, absolute-value

I think this might be an error in *A Survey of Computational Physics: Introductory Computational Science* by Landau. On page 292, he mentions that in order for the logistic map to be stable, we must have

$$\left | \frac{df}{dx} \right |_{x_*}<1$$

The logistic map is given by

$$x_{i+1}=\mu x_i(1-x_i)$$

For the fixed point $x_*=\frac{\mu-1}{\mu}$, he claims that the map is stable if $\mu<3$. But shouldn't he have written that the map is stable if $1<\mu < 3$? My reasoning was that

$$\left | 2-\mu \right | <1$$
$$\to 2-\mu <1 \quad ; \quad -2+\mu < 1$$
$$\to \mu>1 \quad ; \quad \mu <3$$

So why didn't he write $\mu >1$ as a second condition for the map's stability?

Comment: As to why Landau doesn't include the second constraint, it may simply have not been necessary for his purpose. For instance, if you're below $\mu=1$ then the fixed point is not only unstable but in fact (almost) all trajectories diverge. By contrast, just above $\mu=3$ one gets a 2-cycle. So if he's presenting the period-doubling bifurcation at $\mu=3.44949$ then only the $\mu<3$ condition is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but.... It's usual to consider the logistic map as a map on $[0,1]$. I don't know whether the author makes this restriction explicit in the text. With that restriction, $x=(\mu-1)/\mu$ is not in the domain for $\mu<1$, so it doesn't count as a fixed point. So as far as fixed points given by that formula go, we're only considering $\mu\ge1$ anyway, and in that range we have stability for $\mu<3$.